# How does RabbitMQ Handle less messages More Consumers?

Tags: rabbitmq

We have a setup where we have many consumers to a Queue.

The problem it seems like only a subset of those consumers are actually doing work.

Example

One Queue has 120 Consumers and has about 1000 messages?

It seems to only process 20 messages at a time though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're running into the prefetch count limit. I believe the default is 20.

From https://rabbitmq.docs.pivotal.io/36/rabbit-web-docs/consumer-prefetch.html

```
channel.basicQos(10, false); // Per consumer limit
channel.basicQos(15, true);  // Per channel limit
```

Just remember that there are design complexities to working with large numbers of concurrent operations. (It can be done, but be careful that you're maintaining data integrity.)